# How can I send an array of messages in one function call?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What im trying to do is to send a notification to multiply users, when a button is pressed.
I receive a token from each user to a string and I pass it to the message body.
The notification goes successefully to one user, but if I want to send it to multiply users it wont send.

```
const Notification = ({pushTokens}) => {

   const message = {
     to: pushTokens, // the token is recived from parent component as a string
     sound: 'default',
     title: 'title',
     body: 'body',
   };

   function notificationButton(pushTokens) {
     fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(message),
    });
  }

  return(
    <Notification
      onPress={notificationButton}
    > 
    <Text> Notification Button </Text>
   </Notification

}
```

So when I receive the tokens, they come as a string
Example:`console.log('token: ', pushTokens)` it will console:

```
token: ExponentPushTokenPushToken[xxxxxxx...]
token: ExponentPushTokenPushToken[xxxxxxx...]
```

How can I send notification to more then one user?

Comment: these notifications are for google or apple?

Comment: Does the `Notification` prop,  `pushTokens` contain multiple tokens?

Comment: for google, the notification works, but just want to trigger the function for each expo token that comes as a string.

Comment: @user yes, as a string

Comment: @user just like in the example

Comment: @john_1 so pushTokens is a string that contains multiple tokens? Or does is it an array of strings? If it's an array of strings you can just loop over it and send a push notification request for each token in the array

Comment: it's not an array, it's a string. Push token is called for every token that comes in that variable.